# While loop in While loop with an inner join

Tags: php, loops, join, while-loop

For a little project I'm making a bookmark system.

On the front page I want to show all the available categories, and under each category the links within the category.

At the moment I'm stuck with this:

```
$querylinks = "SELECT * FROM links INNER JOIN categorien ON links.categorie_id=categorie.categorie_id; "; 
$results = mysql_query($querylinks);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array('$results')) {
    echo $row['categorie.categorie_id'];
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {/*the links within the category*/
        echo "<a href=" . "http://" . $row['link.link_url'] . ">"
             . $row['link.link_naam'] . "</a><br />";
    }
}
```

The tables "links" and "categories" are joined in the hope that it will get the links within the given category.

I hope I'm not doing something too stupid here, still starting with php.
Do you have an idea why this won't work? I searched throughout stackoverflow but couldn't find something similar.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Does it show wrong results, or nothing at all? Do you get any error messages? If not, have you tried to turn on the error reporting? It also could help if you could you include your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few things wrong here.  In your query statement you have "categorien" after INNER JOIN.  Also, is your table categorie or categories as you have listed in your question?

You should not need two while statements to do this either.  Plus your initial while statement is not correct.  There should not be quotes around $results.

Whenever I am doing a query in php, I always make sure I get the results desired in a mysql query and then copy that properly formatted query into my php code.

I suggest you do that here to verify that the results given are what you expect first.

Then go back and fix your php.  You only need one while loop and it should look something like:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $results) )
```

Comment: hi, thanks for commenting! that's a typo, the tables are links and categorien like in the mysql statement. i want the coding to show something like this: category, link, link, link, category, link, link and so on. i want the links to show beneath the category they are in. it seems inner join isn't fit for the job, do you have any suggestions i could look at?